# Running multiple processses asynchronously

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, multiprocessing

So I have a main() function which needs to continously start >20 different processes every 5 seconds without waiting them to finish as some might take over 5 minutes to finish.
I’ve used threads so far (without joining them) but GIL eventually halts the execution as number of active threads increases.
Could I maybe use some sort of async multiprocessing?

Comment: Hmm, span a new process every 5 seconds that may take more than 5 minutes to finish... This seems like a recipy to overload your pc quite a bit.

Comment: what have you tried ? please show your code or implement a minimal reproducible example of the problem, without enough details about the problem the only answer is "yes you can use some sort of async multiprocessing" , but even then whether this will solve your problem is unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [concurrent.future.ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) to asynchronously run functions in multiple processes without overloading your pc:

```py
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


def background_func(task):
    time.sleep(task)
    return task


with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as pool:
    for task in range(30):
        r = pool.submit(background_func, task) # non-blocking operation
        r.add_done_callback(lambda x: print(f"completed: {x.result()}"))
```